# Deploy multiple LAMP instances on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine

When using click-to-deploy in Google Developer Console, I can only deploy one LAMP vm, where I want to have multiple vm's to create a DTAP solution.

I am able to click deploy LAMP again, but it shows me the already created instance, instead of giving me the option to create a new one.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either I totally missed this, or this has just been added. Anyway: you now have the option to deploy again:

[image]

Comment: No, you didn't miss it, it literally was added yesterday. :)